# Disable JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm writing a Java program where I want to enable a `JButton` which is disabled at the beginning (after completing all text fields in that program).  How would I go about this?

Comment: Cool. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Call

```
button.setEnabled(true);
```

in order to enable it, and

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

in order to disable it. But first [try to understand](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) all this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Add the same DocumentListener to all the text fields. An event is generated every time text is added/removed from the document of any of the text fields.

Then when the event is fired you check all the text fields to make sure they all contain some text. If they all contain text then you can enable the button. If one of them doe not contain text then you disable your button.